# Find ports that *can* be opened

Tags: networking, audit, nmap, port-scanning

I normaly use nmap or just telnet to look for open ports on Windows machines.

I work in a consulting company and we want to discover not only open ports on a machine but ports that *can* be opened.

For instance, if I want to install a database for a customer that listens at 1521. 1521 is not open before I install the database but I want to know if it can be opened or it's blocked (eg. by a firewall), so I ask the customer to open it in advance.

Is there any tool or elegant way to do that?

Thank you
Best regards

Comment: That's not possible and this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nmap can give you this information. The distinction between "open," "can be opened," and "firewalled" is shown in Nmap's output as `open`, `closed`, and `filtered`. For instance:

```
$ sudo nmap scanme.nmap.org

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-01 13:02 CDT
Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221)
Host is up (0.080s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
80/tcp   open     http
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
9929/tcp open     nping-echo

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.39 seconds
```

This shows that `scanme.nmap.org` has TCP ports 22, 80, and 9929 open. My ISP is blocking outbound ports 25, 135, 139, and 445 to prevent spam and Windows worms (and to force me to pay for business-class service if I want to run a mail server). Everything else *could* be opened at some point (`Not shown: 993 closed ports`).

You can further enumerate firewall rules with other scan types (`-sA` will label ports as `unfiltered` or `filtered`) or scripts ([`firewalk`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/firewalk.html) will show which ports are being blocked at which IP hop along your path).

Note that sometimes a firewall will spoof a reply from the target which results in a `closed` verdict. In this case, you can sometimes see a difference in the response TTL values (available in Nmap's XML output, and in future releases in its text output with the `--reason` option); a higher TTL in a closed response means it is coming from a firewall that is closer to you than the target.

Comment: @user3779018 The best thanks you can give me is an upvote and acceptance.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't still vote up, but since I'm really gratefull I'll return here once I can!